# Is it possible to set the MongoDb validator as such that undefined properties are not inserted?

Tags: mongodb, schema, jsonschema

I am trying to implement a database using MongoDB for my REST API that would be able to store and retrieve documents with specific fields.

I can easily use mongoose but I wish to use MongoDB's native driver, as I want to learn MongoDB rather than mongoose.

```
    {
      "$jsonSchema": {
       "bsonType": "object",
       "required": [
          "name",
          "email"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "email": {
          "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "profileImagePath": {
            "bsonType": "string"
          },
          "blogs": {
            "bsonType": ["object"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am expecting to only be able to insert data such as

```
   "name" : "john",
   "email" : "john@gmail.com"
```

Or

```
   "name" : "john",
   "email" : "john@gmail.com",
   "profileImagePath" : "somePath"
```

but not

```
   "name" : "john",
   "email" : "john@gmail.com",
   "height" : "5'11"
```

As height has not been specified in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

so I've been going through MongoDB's documentation and one can specify whether or not additional properties can be inserted into the database or not by changing the default value of `additionalProperties` property.

The documentation states

If true, additional fields are allowed. If false, they are not. If a valid JSON Schema object is specified, additional fields must validate against the schema.

Defaults are true.

To avoid any additional properties from being inserted you'd simply have to add the `additionalProperties` property like so,

```
{
  "$jsonSchema": {
   "bsonType": "object",
   "required": [
      "name",
      "email"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      },
      "email": {
      "bsonType": "string"
      },
      "profileImagePath": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      },
      "blogs": {
        "bsonType": ["object"]
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```